# Should an Angular service return processed data or raw data?

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I'm writing a service to retrieve some data through a HTTP request.

```
app.controller('WarriorsCtrl', function($scope, warriorService) {
  warriorService.getWarriors(function(warriors){
    $scope.warriors = warriors;
  });
});

app.factory('warriorService', function($http) {
  var getWarriors = function(callbackFn) {
    $http.get('/api/warriors').success(function(data) {
      callbackFn(data);
    });
  };

  return {
    getWarriors: getWarriors
  };
});
```

If the controller requires the "warriors" in some processed format is it a good practice to do the processing in the service itself?

eg:

```
var getWarriors = function(callbackFn) {
    $http.get('/api/warriors').success(function(data) {
      var processedWarriors = processData(data);    
      callbackFn(processedWarriors);
    });
};
```

or is it better to use the service to return raw data and do the processing somewhere else such as a filter?

Comment: this isn't something that can be answered with a straightforward "you should always" or "you should never"...  this is something that will vary depending on how much the data is used, how many different ways the data needs to be processed, how much data there is, and about a million other things that make up the core of the app design itself.

Comment: Just ask yourself if you need raw data for something. If you don't, the answer is obvious. And yes, it should use promises and shouldn't use `success`, as the answer explains.

Answer (score 2):

The AngularJS $http Service uses promises to avoid [Callback Hell](http://callbackhell.com/).

Avoid callbacks, instead return promises and use the `.then` method to process data if desired.

```
app.factory('warriorService', function($http) {
  var getWarriors = function() {
    //vvvv RETURN promise
    return $http.get('/api/warriors').then(function onSuccess(response) {
        var data = response.data;
        var warriors = fn(data);
        return warriors;
    });
  };

  return {
    getWarriors: getWarriors
  };
});
```

By returning values to the success handler, the `.then` method creates a new derived promise that resolves with the processed value.

In the controller:

```
app.controller('WarriorsCtrl', function($scope, warriorService) {
  warriorService.getWarriors
   .then (function(warriors){
      $scope.warriors = warriors;
  }).catch(function(errorResponse) {
      console.log(errorResponse.status);
      //throw to chain rejection
      throw errorResponse;
  });
});
```

In addition to avoiding callback hell, the promise retains error information that can be easily used later.

> Because calling the `.then` method of a promise returns a new derived promise, it is easily possible to create a chain of promises. It is possible to create chains of any length and since a promise can be resolved with another promise (which will defer its resolution further), it is possible to pause/defer resolution of the promises at any point in the chain. This makes it possible to implement powerful APIs .
>
> [-- AngularJS $q Service API Reference - Chaining Promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises)

Comment: A lot of good points in your answer. Can I assume that it is preferred to do the processing in the service itself based on your example?

Answer (score 0):

```
It is a good practice to do the processing in the service itself
Avoid using filters for scanning all properties of a complex object graph. 
Use filters for select properties,as Filters can easily be abused and negatively effect performance if not used wisely, for example when a filter hits a large and deep object graph.
```